# How do I undo partitions on my iMac (I keep getting failed message "Mediakit reports not enough space on device for requested operation"

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, high-sierra, disk-utility, partition

Hi I am trying to undo partitions made from a failed Windows 10 installation but it keeps failing or it won't give me the option to undo it on Disk utility.

This is what my partitioned drive looks like[image]

This what happens when I try to delete the partition using the "-" button

[image]

When I try to delete the other drive the "-" button is greyed out. [image]

Please help, I don't know why its doing this. Here are the specs for my computer
[image]

I tried using terminal to delete and reformat the disks but it still would fail to delete the partitions

Here is what My diskutil list looks like
[image: Diskutil list]

Comment: Can you post the output from the command `diskutil list`?. Sometimes the Disk Utility application can display incorrect information.

Comment: I added in the list. Do you see anything that looks like I can do something to it?